# How to get live transaction data from the WAX blockchain without running into timeouts

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, cryptoapi, eos

I would like to have a live view of the WAX Blockchain transactions on my website (similar to this: https://wax.bloks.io/live).
Is there an easy way to get this done without running into timeouts?

thx for your help.

Comment: The website you linked is down. also you may want to be more specific.

Comment: This is a question that I also have. Also, the link in the question is working for me.

Comment: It looks like a lot of the work is done through api's and monitoring contracts from the blockchain producers. A lot of the sites that keep track of crypto spaces are primarily using pre-made/custom apis. A project to recreate the vasteness of bloks would be no easy feature.